# How to block an IP after 5 attempts to the reset password section in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Is there any module or code to ban/Block an IP from accessing my site after 5 attempt to the reset the password section in Prestashop? Recently my site had an attack from a specific ip at least 20000 times. They accessed my sites reset password reset form.

Answer (score 2):

You should ask your hosting about this they must have an monitor on this section meaning that the server will automaticly block these attempts ( in the firewall )

Comment: Thank you.. but the server guys are telling that we should also take care in the prestashop coding part for this.

Comment: Theres multiple options here one of them is a captcha or search a module that takes care of this

Comment: Ok..do you know any module?

Comment: https://addons.prestashop.com/nl/veiligheid-toegang/19495-no-captcha-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess file if you know which IP you want to ban (first line not mandatory) :

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 1.1.1.1`
```